# How to obtain the percentage of each value from a pandas table?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a table with 5 columns: AWA, REM, S1, S2 and SWS. I computed the sum of each column and of each row. And also the percentages of these values. But in order to get the percentages I repeated the same line 5 times. 
Is there a way to improve it in case there were more than 5 columns?

Here is my code and I have also attached an image.

```
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.DataFrame(TABLA, columns=('AWA', 'REM', 'S1', 'S2', 'SWS'))
    df.index='s' + (df.index+1).astype(str) 
    df['xSubject'] = df.sum(axis=1) #sums each colummn

    ######Here starts the repetition:
    df['AWA%'] = df['AWA']/df['AWA'].sum()*100
    df['REM%'] = df['REM']/df['REM'].sum()*100
    df['S1%'] = df['S1']/df['S1'].sum()*100
    df['S2%'] = df['S2']/df['S2'].sum()*100
    df['SWS%'] = df['SWS']/df['SWS'].sum()*100
    df['xSubject%'] = df['xSubject']/df['xSubject'].sum()*100
    ######Here ends the repetition:

    df.loc['xStage'] = df.sum() #sums each row

    df
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `pd.concat` with a reconstruction

```
pd.concat([df,
           pd.DataFrame(df.div(df.sum()).values * 100,
                        columns=df.columns.values + '%')],
          axis=1)
```

---

Consider the `pd.DataFrame` `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 5),
                  columns=('AWA', 'REM', 'S1', 'S2', 'SWS'))

df
```

[image]

and the `%` calculation

```
df.div(df.sum())
```

[image]

Then using the above code

```
pd.concat([df,
           pd.DataFrame(df.div(df.sum()).values * 100,
                        columns=df.columns.values + '%')],
          axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: I also want the sum of each column in the last row. `df.loc['xEstado'] = df.sum()` no longer works and neither: `xEstado = df.sum()`
`df = df.append(xEstado, ignore_index=True)`